# ElasticSearch - query documents: All given labels appear at least one time in a nested document

Tags: search, elasticsearch

Consider a few indexed documents (*employees*) containing nested documents (*skills*) with one property, let's say "*label*", so that each employee is associated with a few skills. I would like to fetch all employees (documents) from the ElasticSearch index, who master a given set of skills, for example "*Python*" and "*Java*".

I am struggling to find a suitable query to ensure that *all* given skills ("Python", "Java") appear **at least once** in the set of skills of an employee, although they **do not** have to appear together!

My mapping is similar to this one:

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "employee": {
      "_all": { "enabled": false },
      "properties": {
        "id" : { "type": "integer" },
        "first_name" : { "type": "string" },
        "last_name" : { "type": "string" },

        "skills": {
          "type": "nested",
          "properties": {
            "label": { "type": "string" },
            "rating": { "type": "integer" }
          }
        }

      }
    }
  }
}
```

So I am looking for any solutions (queries) on how to retrieve the desired results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use **two** `nested` filters combined in a `bool/filter` query, like this:

```
POST /employees/employee/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "skills",
            "query": {
              "term": {
                "skills.label": "python"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "skills",
            "query": {
              "term": {
                "skills.label": "java"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```